# how to hide the table row on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Using ng-repeat i am repeating the tr, Each row will have the one delete button,
when i click on the delete button that parent tr want to hide, how can it possible using angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="affiliate in affiliateList" ng-hide='num == $index'>
      <td>{{affiliate.affName}}</td>
      <td>{{affiliate.affUrl}}</td>
      <td>{{affiliate.associatedId}}</td>
      <td><span class="btn btn-small" ng-click="delete(affiliate.affId); deleteList($index)">Delete</span></td>
    </tr>


$scope.num = 0;
$scope.deleteList = function(index){
    $scope.num = index;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us a plunker that reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code and it doesn't need to write the function.

```
<tr ng-repeat="affiliate in affiliateList" ng-hide='num == $index'>
      <td>{{affiliate.affName}}</td>
      <td>{{affiliate.affUrl}}</td>
      <td>{{affiliate.associatedId}}</td>
      <td><span class="btn btn-small" ng-click="delete(affiliate.affId); num=$index">Delete</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than hiding the row, delete it from the list

html

```
<span class="btn btn-small" ng-click="delete(affiliate)">Delete</span>
```

js

```
$scope.delete = function(item) {
   $scope.affiliates.splice(item, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you're looking for this [Remove Table row dynamically](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/removetablerow)
hope it'll help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to modify delete method as below:

$scope.deleteList = function(index){
    $scope.affiliateList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And you can remove that ng-hide condition.

Comment: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined this error is coming

Comment: You already have $scope.affiliateList array for iterating. Can your share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable (e.g. visibility) for each object, which we can use to keep track of state of each row.

affiliate

```
{
    'visibility': value
    'affId': value,
    'affName': value,
    'affUrl': value,
    'associatedId': value,
}
```

Initialize visibility with true and affId contains unique value for each object.

sample html.js

```
<tr ng-repeat="affiliate in affiliateList track by affiliate.affId" ng-hide='!affiliate.visibility'>
      <td>{{affiliate.affName}}</td>
      <td>{{affiliate.affUrl}}</td>
      <td>{{affiliate.associatedId}}</td>
      <td><span class="btn btn-small" ng-click="delete(affiliate.affId); deleteList(affiliate)">Delete</span></td>
    </tr>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.deleteList = function(affiliate){
     affiliate.visibility = false;
}
```

This should surely solve the problem.